# IUserClaimStore implementation with custom Claim model

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-core, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to use my custom models with the new .net core Identity and been implementing the Store interfaces (IUserStore, IUserLoginStore, etc.) And now that I'm at IUserClaimStore I've hit a snag, the interface expects System.Security.Claims.Claim in the definition. Is there a way around this? The interface doesnt have a base that I can use.

Comment: What is wrong with `System.Security.Claims.Claim`?

Comment: You could create your own `Claim` entity and map it to `System.Security.Claims.Claim` in the implementation of `IUserClaimStore`.  i would suggest go for `AutoMapper` for mapping.

Comment: @trailmax I don't want to introduce dependencies on my Model project which is referenced by Xamarin applications.

Comment: @kewur you already reference Identity package. `System.Security` is hardly a dependency. I'm afraid you have no easy way out of this.

Comment: @Venky not ideal but seems to be the only option.